# What is the most effective dielectric material known to man?

Tags: experimental-physics, dielectric

What is the most effective dielectric medium/material (highest breakdown voltage) known to man?

Is it the vacuum? or are there any materials which could be more effective than the vacuum?

Comment: A plasma with frequency above the critical frequency has a dielectric constant less than unity.